# Getting data-id of multiple divs on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, scroll

## Problem

I have a series of divs each with their own `data-id` and I'm trying to get that id when the user scrolls to that div. Currently, the behavior only works for the first in the series, but not for all ten.

### Objective

- When a user scrolls down the page, determine their position so that I can fetch the corresponding `data-id` from that specific `photo__group` they are viewing.
- Based on what div they've scrolled past, add a class of `is-active` to the corresponding `dot__border`.

### Codepen

https://codepen.io/onlyandrewn/pen/jpmjaE?editors=1010

### scripts.js

```
$(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    getGroupID();
  });

  function getGroupID() {

    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    var group = $(".photo__group");
    var groupID = group.attr("data-id");
    var groupBottom = group.offset().top + group.outerHeight();

    // If a user scrolls down the page and their scroll position is greater than the bottom of the photo group, update the corresponding progress dots. 
    if (scrollPosition > groupBottom) {
        updateProgressDots(groupID);
    } else {
      updateProgressDots(0);
    }
  }

  // This function removes the `is-active` class from all `dot__border` elements, takes the groups `data-id` and adds a `is-active` class to that element in the series i.e. If the user is on the first group, then the first dot / dot border should have the `is-active` class.
  function updateProgressDots(groupID) {

    var dotBorder = $(".dot__border");
    dotBorder.removeClass("is-active");
    dotBorder.eq(groupID).addClass("is-active");    
  }
});
```

### index.html

```
<div class="dots">
  <div class="dot__border is-active">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="photo__group" data-id="1">Photo group #1</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="2">Photo group #2</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="3">Photo group #3</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="4">Photo group #4</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="5">Photo group #5</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="6">Photo group #6</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="7">Photo group #7</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="8">Photo group #8</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="9">Photo group #9</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="10">Photo group #10</div>
```

Comment: `var groupID = group.attr("data-id");`  There are multiple elements with this class.  `attr()` does not return an array of values.  Only the value of the first element.  Most likely you need to iterate over the elements (ex. with `each()`) and perform your logic on each one.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a code snippet of how you might approach this problem with `forEach` I've tried going down that path, but have not been able to get it to return the data for multiple divs.

Comment: `var groups = $(".photo__group"); groups.each(function(index, group){ ...do your logic for each $(group) here... });`

Comment: Look for the [isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport) plugin... I think that this is what you need. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LouysPatriceBessette, but I'd like to tackle my problem without any external libraries.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen check my answer. It works without using external library (slight modification of your existing code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use jQuery `.each` to iterate through all matched elements. Here is your [working code](https://codepen.io/hdas2012/pen/EpXaxQ).

```js
$(function(){
  updateProgressDots(0);
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    getGroupID();
  });
  
  function getGroupID() {
    
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".photo__group").each(function(index){
     
      
      
      var group = $(this);
    var groupID = group.attr("data-id");
    var groupBottom = group[0].offsetHeight+group[0].offsetTop;
     
    // If a user scrolls down the page and their scroll position is greater than the bottom of the photo group, update the corresponding progress dots. 
    if (scrollPosition > groupBottom) {
        updateProgressDots(groupID);
    }
    });
    
  }
  
  // This function removes the `is-active` class from all `dot__border` elements, takes the groups `data-id` and adds a `is-active` class to that element in the series i.e. If the user is on the first group, then the first dot / dot border should have the `is-active` class.
  function updateProgressDots(groupID) {
    
    var dotBorder = $(".dot__border");
    dotBorder.removeClass("is-active");
    dotBorder.eq(parseInt(groupID)).addClass("is-active");    
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.dots {
  position: fixed;
  right: 48px;
  bottom: 48px;
}

.dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dot__border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.dot__border.is-active {
  border: 1px solid #c62828;
}
.dot__border.is-active .dot {
  background: #c62828;
}

.photo__group {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c62828;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dots">
  <div class="dot__border is-active">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dot__border">
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="photo__group" data-id="1">Photo group #1</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="2">Photo group #2</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="3">Photo group #3</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="4">Photo group #4</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="5">Photo group #5</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="6">Photo group #6</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="7">Photo group #7</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="8">Photo group #8</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="9">Photo group #9</div>
<div class="photo__group" data-id="10">Photo group #10</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic. Do you mind explain your thought process about the changes you made to my code? Specifically the change to `groupBottom` and calling the `updateProgressDots` function up at the top.

Comment: The only thing that does not work as intended is when you scroll down the page and scroll back up the page to the first `photo_group` the first `dot__border` does not get the `is-active` class.

Answer (score 1):

I played with your script.

First, I really dislike to perform useless jQuery lookups for elements in an event handler that fires like a machine gun... Like `scroll`. That is a performance concern. The elements are static, so you should lookup for them outside this handler.

So I gathered all the useful `group` params in an array of objects first.

Then, on scroll, iterate through those objects to find the group in view.

**Bonus**, I added a "trigger" parameter... That's to decide when to update the dots. I think that the middle of the viewport is the right place... The active dot will then represent the group that is "most in viewport".

Have a look ;)

```
$(function(){
  console.clear();

  // Dots will be updated when at the middle of the viewport
  var scrollTrigger = $(window).height()/2;

  var groups = $(".photo__group");

  // Get all group params
  var groupDataArray = [];
  groups.each(function(index,group){
    var data = {};

    data.groupID = $(group).data("id");
    data.groupBottom = $(group).offset().top + $(group).outerHeight();
    data.groupTop = $(group).offset().top;

    //console.log(data);
    groupDataArray.push(data);
  });

  // If a user scrolls down the page and their scroll position is greater than the bottom of the photo group, update the corresponding progress dots.
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    // Look in the groupDataArray to find which group is in viewport
    groupDataArray.forEach(function(obj,index){

      if(obj.groupTop < scrollPosition + scrollTrigger && obj.groupBottom > scrollPosition + scrollTrigger){
        console.log(obj.groupID);
        updateProgressDots(obj.groupID)
      }
    })
  });  // END scroll

  // This function removes the `is-active` class from all `dot__border` elements, takes the groups `data-id` and adds a `is-active` class to that element in the series i.e. If the user is on the first group, then the first dot / dot border should have the `is-active` class.
  function updateProgressDots(groupID) {    
    var dotBorder = $(".dot__border");
    dotBorder.removeClass("is-active");
    dotBorder.eq(groupID-1).addClass("is-active");  // eq() is zero-based !
  }
}); // End ready
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zLzYXP?editors=1111)